# How to improve kafka consumer performance PHP/RDKafka

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

I'm consuming messages from kafka using php rdkafka and high-level consuming approach as it is described here https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka/phpdoc/rdkafka.examples-high-level-consumer.html

The issue I have is that I have to wait for message approx around 3s to be read by consumer, topic has 20 partitions and there are 10 consumers in same group, even if there is only 1 consumer it is taking 3s to read message from kafka

Comment: Increase consumers to number of partitions.

Comment: I did, but time for 1 consumer to get message is 3s thats quite long

Comment: Did you use kafka terminal command:kafka-console-consumer? What's your Kafka server settings?

Comment: I did not, I'm using PHP RdKafka library, configuration is basic. Running it in dev mode in docker.